# Set Default limit of per page in custom grid

Tags: magento2

How to set Default limit per page in custom grid in magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can set limit per page in custom module using below code in block file using `_prepareLayout` method,

Inside block file,

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            // create pager block for collection 
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'my.custom.pager'
            );
            // // assign collection to pager we can set 8 per page
            $pager->setLimit(8)->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);// set pager block in layout
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Is this not possible using admin->products->categories->design->layout update xml ? to update for every category page limit